If I have a series of switches, can I just debounce the last one?
I started thinking about this while writing up two other questions (here and here) and in reading answers and comments. I have a pushbutton switch driving a D flip flop which controls a relay, so I have, essentially, two switches in a series. I was thinking of another way to represent that and have these two situations:

In the first one (in purple), I have a master power switch (A) and a momentary pushbutton switch (B). In the 2nd one (in green), which is close to what I'm doing, I have a momentary pushbutton (C), which controls a D FF (D), which turns a relay (E) on and off.
In both cases I have 2 switches in a series. Switch A's output goes only to B. Switch C's output only goes to the D FF, and then to Relay E.
Since the output of the 1st switch in each series goes only to the 2nd switch, is there any need to debounce Switch A or Switch C if I have a debouncing circuit after Button B or the switch on Relay E?
My reasoning is that the bounce from A won't go to any component until B is pressed, so there's no need to debounce A. On the 2nd circuit, the output from C does go to the FF, so the FF might bounce, but it seems to me if that causes any extra jitter or bounce in the output for Relay K, that a debouncing circuit on the output on K would handle any issues in the main circuit.
Is there a need to debounce A and C in a case like this, or only debounce the output of the last in a series of switches?

I think someone asked on your previous two questions about why the relay contacts that act as a power supply switch are debounced. For what purpose is the relay output used, powering some device or simulating a switch or something else?

I asked, but there was no clear answer and, after thinking about it, thought it would be good as a separate question. (This is why I'm doing this project - I thought it'd be small and simple, but I'm having to learn so many topics that will help me later, so all the help I'm getting and all I'm learning is great!)

You need to debounce C, because if you don't, the DFF may toggle once, twice, or any number of odd or even count as the contacts have oxidation, dirt, grease or just actually bounce mechanically. The debouncing is needed so that you get one clean and reliable button push event, to make the DFF to toggle reliably only once, when you push and release the button.
So pushing the C button may or may not toggle the relay if the signal from button C is scratchy, and releasing the C button can also be scratchy.
So only because DFF needs a clean signal, the C button must be debounced.
The DFF then either turns on or off the relay contacts E, and if that contact bounce is relevant or not depends on what circuit is being driven with the bouncy contacts E.
The question of for what purpose you would need to debounce any other button, switch or contact than C thus remains unknown, because the usage of the switched power supply or signal is unknown.

Thank you for pointing out the FF is edge triggered. I was not thinking about that when I was looking things over. Good point. A theoretical variation: If DFF depended in CLK being high, so it depended on the state, not the edge, then would it still need debouncing? (Asking for understanding - I know it's not the case!)

@Tango It depends what you mean - i.e. how you think this imaginary FF would react to a button signal that toggles multiple times every time when pressed or released. Sometimes that noise is bad, sometimes it does not matter.

@Tango OK, but since you did not tell for what purpose the relay output or A/B outputs are used, it leaves this question hanging if A/B/E contacts should or should not be debounced.

Okay - It all makes sense. I have some other switches that'll go on this PCB that connect to an ESP32. I'm looking into using a 14490 to debounce everything. That's C and E in this diagram and 4 other DTST switches where I only have to debounce one side of those 4 switches.

@Tango Yes but saying the outputs go to ESP32 means nothing - is the relay output driving the 3.3V power supply or just a GPIO input? Or what do they do and control in the ESP32?

The relay is driving 4 more relays that allow the DPST switches to turn external devices on and off. With those 4 relays, there's a connector on the PCB so the wires come in from the power supply, to my PCB, through a relay, then through a DPST, then back to a connector going to the device. Totally separate power supplies (which is why I'm using relays instead of transistors). I'm replacing the normal physical switches used to turn those devices on. I'm debouncing the side of the DPST going to the ESP32, but NOT the side of the switch going to an external device. (Cont'd)

I'm replacing the physical switches for the external devices with my DPSTs. Those devices, if they need their power switches debounced, will already have that circuitry on their boards. Also, since I do not want any connection between my power supply and theirs, that's another reason for not debouncing anything for the devices.

Here's a quick whiteboard diagram of what I'm doing (https://imgur.com/a/WkKIiC8). Push the button and it triggers the D FF, which turns the 1st relay on or off. When that relay goes on, it turns on 4 more. (I only used 1 in the diagram.) The circuit for the off-board devices is in green. From the plug, the line goes on, through the relay switch, through one side of a DPST, then back out. The DPST replaces the device's own power switch, so if the external device needs debouncing, it would already have it. The other half of the DPSST switch is debounced and connects to a GPIO pin on the ESP32.

If you are reading the relay contacts with ESP32, does it really need debouncing? Generally MCU would just read the pin state and if needed it would run software debouncing. Unless it's an interrupt pin which needs a debounced signal. In which case a slow RC signal on an IRQ pin is a bad idea. But slow RC signals on any CMOS input may be a bad idea unless the input has even a small hysteresis, which many MCUs could have.

I'm using ESPHome and have asked, on that forum, about debouncing. Someone has responded, but not someone who knows the source code, so I'm still trying to find out about that. I forgot, in my diagram, to specify that the ESP32 does read the state of the relay, but the main use of the relay (and using a push button and DFF) is to have a "master switch" that will lock out the attached devices, so they won't just come on when power comes back on. For ESPHome, interrupts aren't needed. I do need clarification for that point from someone who knows ESPHome closely.

Just got an answer on the ESPHome debouncing - for binary sensors (which is what I'm using), there's a delay function that does the debouncing. I've also found the 14490 debouncing chip, which has 6 gates on it. I could probably use that for this project - all it needs, externally, is one cap and it could debounce all my switches on this project.

@Tango The hardware debounce chip will be useless if software does it for you.

For anything with the ESP32, yes. But for other switches, it could help. Still going over what it will and won't help.

@Tango If the other chips have regular pushbuttons, a relay contacts will be just as bouncy as the regular pushbuttons, so anything should work. If the original buttons are e.g. part of a scanned button/keyboard matrix, you must not connect any capacitors there.

So, for where I need debouncing, no problem with using the 14490? And if the switches are debounced through software or something else (like with a scanned matrix), then it's not my problem. Is that correct?
